# Django ModelFormSet clicking "Submit" saves form but does not update to database

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

**Background:**
I'm building a personal dictionary web-application, and have a queryset of terms and definitions. In my web app, I have an edit page, where I want to show a ModelFormSet that allows the user to edit any/all entries, and delete them if needed - the form has a delete button for each row and a submit button to save changes to the form.

The **current issue is that when I click on a set to edit, the formset shows up correctly, and when I change a term and hit "Submit" the form updates to show the change. However, when I go back to my "View Set" page, the term hasn't been updated, which I assume means the change didn't go through to the actual database - the form itself was simply submitted**. This is what I would like to currently fix, and I also want to make it so that the delete button deletes the entry.

**What I've Tried:**
I've gone through every StackOverflow question I could find relating to the topic, and various solutions were: add an instance parameter when passing in "request.POST", re-initialize the formset after saving, change the "action" url in the HTML page, etc., but every solution I try either results in another error or doesn't change anything.

I also checked the documentation but the examples provided were for simpler examples, and I'm not sure where exactly my error is in this case.

Finally, I also used {{ form.errors }} to see if the forms were being validated, and this resulted in an empty bracket and no issues, so I *think* I know for sure that the form is being validated, and the POST request is working.

**Code:**
MODELS.PY

```
class Set(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 64, null = False, blank = False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = False, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 


class Entry(models.Model):
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    term = models.TextField()
    definition = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.term
```

FORMS.PY

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from .models import Set, Entry

class SetForm(ModelForm):       # Form that maps to Set

    class Meta: 
        model = Set
        fields = ['title', 'description']

class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Entry
        fields = ['set', 'term', 'definition']
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def editEntry(request, set_id):
        EntryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Entry, EntryForm, extra=0)
        set_obj=Set.objects.get(id=set_id)      
        entry_list = set_obj.entry_set.order_by("term")
        entry_formset=EntryFormSet(queryset=entry_list)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            instances=entry_formset.save()
                for instance in instances:
                        instance.save()
                        entry_formset = EntryFormSet(queryset=instances)
        else: 
            entry_formset = EntryFormSet(queryset=entry_list)#formset_factory(entry_form)
        return render (request, 'dictTemplates/editEntries.html', {'entry_formset': entry_formset})
```

EDIT ENTRIES.HTML

```
<h1 style="text-align:center"><strong></center>Edit Entries Page</strong></h1>


        <form method="POST" action = "">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {{ entry_formset.management_form }}
        <center><table id="entriesFormSet" class="table"> 
                <input type ="submit" value ="Submit Form">
                <tr>
                    <th><h3>Terms</h3></th>
                    <th><h3>Definitions</h3></th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                        {% for form in entry_formset %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ form.term }}</td>
                                <td>{{ form.definition }}</td>
                                <td class="delete-entry-button"><input type = "submit" value = "Delete Term"></td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table></center>
        </form>
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='Home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='About'),
    path('sets/', views.sets, name='Sets'),
    path('sets/create/', views.createSet, name='createSet'),
    path('sets/edit/(?P<set_id>[\d]+)', views.editSet, name='editSet'),
    path('sets/delete/(?P<set_id>[\d]+)', views.deleteSet, name='deleteSet'), 
    path('sets/view/(?P<set_id>[\d]+)', views.viewSet, name='viewSet'),
    path('entrys/create/(?P<set_id>[\d]+)', views.createEntry, name='createEntry'),
    path('entrys/edit/(?P<set_id>[\d]+)', views.editEntry, name='editEntry'),
    path('entrys/delete/(?P<entry_id>[\d]+)', views.deleteEntry, name='deleteEntry'),
]
```

The desired result is that clicking "Submit" results in an updated form plus changes in the database, but right now, clicking "Submit" only results in an updated form at that moment - clicking to another page or any other action makes the form revert to the original state.

**I think the problem is that my Submit button somehow isn't "mapping" to saving the form into the database, that there's a missing connection there somewhere, but I'm not sure how to find it.**

Please let me know if I should format/post this question differently, as it's my first SO question. Thank you so much!! Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something else is also wrong, but your view doesn't instantiate your formset well. Try with the following code:

```
EntryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Entry, EntryForm, extra=0)    
if request.method == 'POST':
    entry_formset=EntryFormSet(data=request.POST)
    if entry_formset.is_valid():
        entry_formset.save()  # this will save all the instances
else:
    set_obj=Set.objects.get(id=set_id)      
    entry_list = set_obj.entry_set.order_by("term")
    entry_formset=EntryFormSet(queryset=entry_list)

return render(request, 'dictTemplates/editEntries.html', {'entry_formset': entry_formset})
```

If you want you may assign return value to formset save like `instances = entry_formset.save()` and debug which instances are saved (that returned value will be a list of those that are saved to database) by passing it to template together with formset in context and show the value in template.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help! I will try this fix and see what happens, and update - thanks!